# NSDateformatter Converting date to string

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am having the following date and time 2013-04-25 10:42:44 +0000. When i convert the above date to string, i am getting the output as 2013-04-25 16:12:44. Following is the code i am using to convert the date to string

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *dateStr= [dateFormatter    stringFromDate:date]];
    NSLog(@"dateStr--%@",dateStr);
```

Comment: Timezone.  Generally an NSDate value is UTC, while the NSDateFormatter defaults to your local time zone (India).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets asked over and over (but is difficult to find via search).

When you log an `NSDate` object, you will always get the date in UTC format. This is how the `description` method of `NSDate` is currently implemented.

As long as the difference you are seeing can be accounted for based on your local timezone relative to UTC, then what you are seeing it correct and expected behavior.

BTW - there is no reason to set the date formatter's timezone to the "system" timezone. This is already done by default. Same for the locale. Only set the timezone or locale if you want something different from the current values.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a timezone issue. Set your formatters time zone to GMT:

```
    dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the variable `date` gets initialized via `[NSDate date]`.
Maybe the quite extensive answer in the follwing topic is helpful here, too.

[Does [NSDate date] return the local date and time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214947/help-me-understand-nsdate-date)